# Angular architecture for a sorting directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Being quite new to angular, I am searching the best way to achieve a quite simple task.

My aim is to update in a database, through angular $resource service, the order (I have a position attribute) of a Project model.

I have the following template structure :

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sortable" my-drag-list>
        <tr ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-class="{warning: !project.publish}">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{project.title}}</td>
            <td>{{project.date|date: 'MMMM yyyy'}}</td>
            <td><a ng-href="{{project.link}}" target="blank">{{project.link}}</a></td>
            <td><a ng-href="#/projects/{{project.id}}/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
            <td><a ng-click="deleteProject(project)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-show="data.saveSort" my-update-sort-button>Save new sort</button>
```

`tr` in my `tbody` element are movable. When I click on the `button` element (which is out of the scope created by the `ng-repeat` directive), I want to update my database whith new position values, which are determined by the dom position of each `tr` (upper `tr` will have a smaller position value).

At first glance, I intends to do a my-update-sort-button directive with the following :

```
var link = function(scope, el){

    el.on('click', function(){
        var els = el.parent().find('tr');

        for(var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++){
            Projects.update({id: els.eq(i).data('projectId')}, {position: i});
        }
    });
};
```

But I am not sure about the "quality" of such solution. I do not like the fact of adding data-project-id attribute on my tr element.

Thanks for any ideas or solutions for this case !

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to save the sort criteria? or is it important that the positions are saved as well.

Comment: @pixelbits I am trying to save the position of the project (which depends on his position in the DOM) in a position attribute that is present in the Project model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep info about "project" position in it's model. When "project" is moved you save this info to its model. Do it in "my-drag-list".

When click to update button you just send info from model without scanning the DOM:

```
var link = function(scope, el){

  el.on('click', function(){
      var model;
      for(var i = 0, len = scope.model.projects.length; i<len; i++){
          model = scope.model.projects[i];
          Projects.update({id: model .id}, {position: model.position});
      }
  });
};
```

Even better don't send a lot of requests to server. Send one request with all info together.